# How to configure maven to use different artifact?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I m new to Spring framework. Need a help.

When I create a simple Spring Starter Project using STS (Type : maven, Dependency: Spring Web), it throws an error on POM.xml saying "Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM..."
This looks like a firewall issue that maven repositories cannot be downloaded from internet in my network. But I have a artifactory where my network can access and download
all required jars from here. Something like: http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/spring-framework which has a username/password also.

So how do I tell maven to download dependencies from this repository instead of going outside and get it. Can anyone help here.

Thank you,

Comment: In your maven settings.xml file, you can add repository. Refer the following link. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html. Then you need to update your IDE to use the updated settings.xml file.

Comment: you should add a `<repository>..` section to your pom pointing to the company repo. After doing that, you should also clean the local maven repo, to get rid of any malformed pom-s you downloaded previously. (delete the user/.m2/repository folder). Alternatively, use `mvn -U ..` to force it to re-download the dependencies